# I want to use labels for my Rails 4.0 application such that they appear on the form as well as in activerecord error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have checked several posts here and none of them seemed to work for me. I don't know what I am missing.

The ruby documentation here http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/label, seems to have the answer, but it is not clear how to interpret some text. For eg.,

```
helpers:
  label:
    post:
      body: "Write your entire text here"
```

Is this the text one should put in the en.yml file as-is (replacing the post with my own model name and body with my own field name etc?) I tried that and it didn't work. Then I tried to put this text in the app/helpers/"modelname"_helper.rb file. Didn't work there either.

```
helpers:
  label:
    representative:
      fname: "First Name"
```

After these edits, in my view I have the code as follows:

```
<%= f.label :fieldname %>
```

In my case:

```
<%= f.label :fname %>
```

At this point when I run my app, I am expecting my custom label that to be shown on the form. It doesn't. It just shows Fname

When I see similar posts on stackoverflow even there I see the same convention being used. Looks like I have two issues going on. 1) Understanding this convention and how to interpret it and 2) The solution to my actual issue itself.

I know I can use `<%= f.label :fname, 'First Name' %>`, but because I am validating for fname in the model for presence, the error message says "Fname is required". I would like it to say "First Name" is required.

How else can I do this?

Please help.

Comment: WHy don't you use :first_name instead of :fname? Then it should read First name is required

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. fname is just an example. There are hundreds of other fields out there, that I need a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate the names of your model attributes, put something like the following in `config/i18n/en.yml`:

```
activerecord:
  attribute:
    representative:
      fname: "First name"
      body: "Write something here"
```

Error messages for specific attributes and specific errors can be overriden too:

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    models:
      representative:
        attributes:
          body:
            blank: "Body cannot be blank"
```

But I think your best option is to create a new translatable for the custom body label. In your form:

```
= f.label :body, t(:write_text)
```

In your `en.yml`:

```
write_text: "Write something here"
```